# NestJs Swagger how to add custom favicon

Tags: swagger, favicon, nestjs

I am trying to add a custom favicon to my NestJs documentation. However, I am a bit lost on how the path file gets resolved and not sure how to achieve this.

I am using nestjs/swagger module version 3.1.0 and trying to pass the path file like so when initializing the Swagger Module.

My **main.ts** file

```
SwaggerModule.setup('/v1/docs', app, document, {
    customCss: CUSTOM_STYLE,
    customSiteTitle: 'My API Documentation',
    customfavIcon: './public/favicon.jpg'
});
```

Searched on the github issues and didn't find anything useful. And as you can see from the code I was able to modify the CSS styles, but I cannot figure out how to make the favicon custom.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Do you have static resources set up for your server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added the custom favicon to my swagger docs using following:

The first thing you make sure is, in your `main.ts`, the app is initialized with the following:

```
const app: NestExpressApplication = await NestFactory.create(...)
```

To serve static content you must initialize your app with `NestExpressApplication`.

The next thing is to allow the Nest application to look for public content using the following in your `main.ts` after initialization:

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
```

Also, create a public directory in your root of the application and paste your `favicon.jpg` file in it.

Now its time to initialize the Swagger in `main.ts`

```
SwaggerModule.setup('/v1/docs', app, document, {
    customCss: CUSTOM_STYLE,
    customSiteTitle: 'My API Documentation',
    customfavIcon: '../favicon.jpg'
});
```

You must give a relative path to the root of the application like `../favicon.jpg` in case our `main.ts` is in `src` folder in root of the application.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I was not using the useStaticAssets function. I've added it now. Shouldn't customFavIcon be **"../public/favicon.jpg"** ? Anyway I've tried both like that and as you present your example and they both result in an error of type:
_GET http://localhost:3000/v1/public/favicon.jpg 404 (Not Found)_ .

What confuses me is how are the /v1/docs and /v1/public work together for handling the requests.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: if you are using static serving, then your URL should be `GET localhost:3000/favicon.jpg`

Comment: Worked by configuring it like so on Swagger Options:
`customfavIcon: '/favicon.png'`. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, just host your favicon and reference it with external url

```
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, getSwaggerDocument(app), {
    ...
    customfavIcon:
      'https://[your-bucket-url].com/.../anything.png',
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on pravindot17's answer, now there's the [`@nestjs/serve-static`](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static#serve-static) package for hosting static files. Which avoid us from type-casting the Nest.js client and relying on our implicit assumption that we're running an Express-backed Nest.js server.

After installing the package, you hook it into your `src/app.module.ts`. This configuration expects that the root of your project has a `/public/` folder where you store your static assets.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    // Host static files in ../public under the /static path.
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      /**
       * Config options are documented:
       * https://github.com/nestjs/serve-static/blob/master/lib/interfaces/serve-static-options.interface.ts
       */
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public'),
      serveRoot: '/static',
    }),
    // ... 
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now my own preference is using an absolute path rather than relative, as it makes it independent from the path we picked to host our API documentation under.

```
SwaggerModule.setup('/v1/docs', app, document, {
    customfavIcon: '/static/favicon.jpg'
});
```

One last note is that this configuration hosts static files from `/static/*`, this is done to prevent that API calls to non-existing endpoints show an error message to the end-user that the static file cannot be found.

Otherwise, all 404's on non-existing endpoints will look something like:

```
{"statusCode":404,"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/me/my-project/public/index.html'"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions that pravindot17 said, but it worked for me adding `"assets": ["public/**/*"]` on `compilerOptions` in `nest-cli.json` (nest CLI config file) as the code below, cause Nest didn't build the public folder on dist folder:

`nest-cli.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "assets": ["public/**/*"]
  }
}
```